# Simple example of how to use ast.NodeVisitor?

Tags: python, python-2.6, abstract-syntax-tree

Does anyone have a simple example using ast.NodeVisitor to walk the abstract syntax tree in Python 2.6? The difference between visit and generic_visit is unclear to me, and I cannot find any example using google codesearch or plain google.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

`ast.visit` -- unless you override it in a subclass, of course -- when called to visit an `ast.Node` of class `foo`, calls `self.visit_foo` if that method exists, otherwise `self.generic_visit`. The latter, again in its implementation in class `ast` itself, just calls `self.visit` on every child node (and performs no other action).

So, consider, for example:

```
>>> class v(ast.NodeVisitor):
...   def generic_visit(self, node):
...     print type(node).__name__
...     ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)
...
```

Here, we're overriding `generic_visit` to print the class name, but *also* calling up to the base class (so that all children will also be visited).  So for example...:

```
>>> x = v()
>>> t = ast.parse('d[x] += v[y, x]')
>>> x.visit(t)
```

emits:

```
Module
AugAssign
Subscript
Name
Load
Index
Name
Load
Store
Add
Subscript
Name
Load
Index
Tuple
Name
Load
Name
Load
Load
Load
```

But suppose we didn't care for Load nodes (and children thereof -- if they had any;-). Then a simple way to deal with that might be, e.g.:

```
>>> class w(v):
...   def visit_Load(self, node): pass
...
```

Now when we're visiting a Load node, `visit` dispatches, NOT to `generic_visit` any more, but to our new `visit_Load`... which doesn't do anything at all.  So:

```
>>> y = w()
>>> y.visit(t)
Module
AugAssign
Subscript
Name
Index
Name
Store
Add
Subscript
Name
Index
Tuple
Name
Name
```

or, suppose we also wanted to see the actual names for Name nodes; then...:

```
>>> class z(v):
...   def visit_Name(self, node): print 'Name:', node.id
... 
>>> z().visit(t)
Module
AugAssign
Subscript
Name: d
Index
Name: x
Store
Add
Subscript
Name: v
Index
Tuple
Name: y
Name: x
Load
Load
```

But, NodeVisitor is a class because this lets it store information during a visit. Suppose all we want is the set of names in a "module".  Then we don't need to override `generic_visit` any more, but rather...:

```
>>> class allnames(ast.NodeVisitor):
...   def visit_Module(self, node):
...     self.names = set()
...     self.generic_visit(node)
...     print sorted(self.names)
...   def visit_Name(self, node):
...     self.names.add(node.id)
... 
>>> allnames().visit(t)
['d', 'v', 'x', 'y']
```

This kind of thing is a more typical use case than ones requiring overrides of `generic_visit` -- normally, you're only interested in a few kinds of nodes, like we are here in Module and Name, so we can just override `visit_Module` and `visit_Name` and let ast's `visit` do the dispatching on our behalf.

Comment: Great, I would like to understand a bit more the difference between compiler.ast ans ast now...

Comment: How can I visit and register **class** using NodeVisitor?

Comment: @VeLKerr you need to define a function `def visit_Class(self,node):` and then print it or do whatever you want to do. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html#compiler.ast.Node.getChildNodes) and then search for Class node in the table

Answer (score 16):

Looking at the code in [ast.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ast.py) it's not that hard to copy paste and roll your own walker. E.g.

```
import ast
def str_node(node):
    if isinstance(node, ast.AST):
        fields = [(name, str_node(val)) for name, val in ast.iter_fields(node) if name not in ('left', 'right')]
        rv = '%s(%s' % (node.__class__.__name__, ', '.join('%s=%s' % field for field in fields))
        return rv + ')'
    else:
        return repr(node)
def ast_visit(node, level=0):
    print('  ' * level + str_node(node))
    for field, value in ast.iter_fields(node):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, ast.AST):
                    ast_visit(item, level=level+1)
        elif isinstance(value, ast.AST):
            ast_visit(value, level=level+1)


ast_visit(ast.parse('a + b'))
```

Prints out

```
Module(body=[<_ast.Expr object at 0x02808510>])
  Expr(value=BinOp(op=Add()))
    BinOp(op=Add())
      Name(id='a', ctx=Load())
        Load()
      Add()
      Name(id='b', ctx=Load())
        Load()
```

Answer (score 6):

`generic_visit` is called when a custom visitor (ie visit_Name) can't be found. Here's a piece of code I wrote recently with ast.NodeVisitor: [https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/blob/80ead76ab428100ffeb01109c7fc0d94f1048af2/py/_code/_assertionnew.py](https://github.com/pypy/pypy/blob/master/py/_code/_assertionnew.py) It interprets the AST nodes to gain debugging information about some of them and falls back in with `generic_visit` when a special implementation isn't provided.