# Using eval() with Undefined Variables

Tags: python

I want to create a Python script that takes in a string representation of a dictionary and outputs a list of tuples representing the items of the dictionary. The rub is, I want it to take in variables that have not been defined. An example illustrates this best:

Input: `{'test': test}`

Output: `[('test': test)]`

I've created some code to read in the dictionary and define the variables that haven't yet been defined, but when I `eval()` the result, it substitutes in the actual value of the variable rather than the variable name.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instr = sys.argv[1]
    success = False
    while not success:
        try:
            indict = eval(instr)
            success = True
        except NameError, e:
            defname = re.search("name '([^\']*)' is not defined", str(e))
            locals()[defname.group(1)] = 0
    print indict
```

I was hoping, for the above defined input value, that the dict it printed out would match the input string perfectly, but instead it has substituted in the value of 0 for `test`. Thus the script prints out:

```
{'test': 0}
```

I have tried `ast.literal_eval`, but it throws a `ValueError: malformed string` for any variable name in the literal, even if it's been defined.

Thus, my question is: Is there a way to convert the input dictionary without losing the variable names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by substituting in unique strings for the names of the variables. This produces the desired result:

```
import sys
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instr = sys.argv[1]
    subs = []
    success = False
    while not success:
        try:
            indict = eval(instr)
            success = True
        except NameError, e:
            defname = re.search("name '([^\']*)' is not defined", str(e)).group(1)
            subs.append(defname)
            locals()[defname] = '//substitute{%d}' % (len(subs) - 1)
    outlist = indict.items()
    outstr = str(outlist)
    for i, sub in enumerate(subs):
        outstr = outstr.replace("'//substitute{%d}'" % i, sub)
    print outstr
```

Input: `{"test": test}`

Output: `[('test', test)]`

Input: `{"test": [{"test": test}, {word: "word"}]}`

Output: `[('test', [{'test': test}, {word: 'word'}])]` (note that this is desirable, I don't want the inner dictionary zipped).

The minor downside is that I can never have whatever substitution string I elect to use anywhere in the input string, but I am reasonably certain this will not be an issue for what I wish to use this script for.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `ast` module, but not `literal_eval`.  Walk the tree, when you find a variable reference, just insert the name of the variable into the output.

Comment: According to the definition of `ast.walk` (and my own experimentation), the nodes are given back in no particular order, so I cannot output a reliable representation of the input string with it.

Comment: `ast.walk` isn't what you want.  You need to visit each node in the tree.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515357/simple-example-of-how-to-use-ast-nodevisitor  for an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can trick `eval` into giving you what you want:

```
class Reflector(object):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return name

s = "{'test':test}"

print eval(s, globals(), Reflector())
```

produces:

```
{'test': 'test'}
```

The usual caveats about the dangers of `eval` hold though: if you have any doubts about the source of these strings, you are opening yourself up for hacking.

Comment: I have no doubts about the source.

Comment: This is interesting, but only gets me to the point of having a string with the name of the variable instead of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is that you want to evaluate the name of a variable instead of the value of that variable. In particular, `{'test':test}` would never be the output of printing a dictionary because `test` is not a value in python, it is possibly the name of a variable. The closest you can get is assigning

```
locals()[defname.group(1)] = defname.group(1)
```

to get

```
{'test':'test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a reasonable workaround is to pass `eval` something that preserves undefined variables in a useful way.  You can pass any `dict` subclass to eval, and you can override the `__missing__` method of dict to return an 'undefined variable' object:

```
>>> class Var(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "Var(%r)" % (self.name,)
... 
>>> class UndefSubst(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         return Var(key)
... 
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> eval("{'baz': quux, 1: foo}", UndefSubst(locals()))
{1: 'bar', 'baz': Var('quux')}
```