# How to extract a part of a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, split

I have this string:

```
-1007.88670550662*p**(-1.0) + 67293.8347365694*p**(-0.416543501823503)
```

but actually I have a lot of string like this:

```
a*p**(-1.0) + b*p**(c)
```

where a,b and c are double. And I would like to extract a,b and c of this string. How can I do this using Python?

Comment: use regex and pull the doubles out as you parse it.

Comment: Thank you but i don't know regex... How can i use it ?

Comment: @GuyDavis See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: @GuyDavis sounds like a good opportunity to learn regex.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html) is some very clear guidance with examples, including numbers!

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
s = '-1007.88670550662*p**(-1.0) + 67293.8347365694*p**(-0.416543501823503)'
pattern = r'-?\d+\.\d*'  

a,_,b,c = re.findall(pattern,s)
print(a, b, c)
```

**Output**

```
('-1007.88670550662', '67293.8347365694', '-0.416543501823503')
```

`s` is your test strings and what not, `pattern` is the regex pattern, we are looking for floats, and once we find them using [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) we assign them back to `a`,`b`,`c`

Note this method works only if your string is in format of what you've given. else you can play with the pattern to match what you want.

Edit like most people stated in the comments if you need to include a `+` in front of your positive numbers you can use this pattern `r'[-+]?\d+\.\d*'`

Comment: You probably want `pattern = r'-?\d+\.\d+'` to catch the possible minus sign.

Comment: and a possible plus sign

Comment: Doesn't this matches `-1.0`?

Comment: @PedroLobito it does and i disregard it, like my answer states, if the string is given in that exact format as in `a*p**(-1.0) + b*p**(c)` like op stated, then it has no issues

Comment: @PedroLobito: The `-1.0` is assigned to `_`, which is used as a throw-away variable by convention.

Comment: Also `-1007.` could be a valid floating point number. You can change the pattern to `r'[-+]?\d+\.\d*'` to account for that

Comment: @quasoft while you are correct about the `-1007.`, which I added thanks :D, I feel the need for the `+` in front is not really needed, since OP didn't state it, and  the little sample given doesn't show a `+` for positive numbers, I will leave a comment about it though.

Answer (score 1):

Using the reqular expression

```
(-?\d+\.?\d*)\*p\*\*\(-1\.0\)\s*\+\s*(-?\d+\.?\d*)\*p\*\*\((-?\d+\.?\d*)\)
```

We can do

```
import re

pat = r'(-?\d+\.?\d*)\*p\*\*\(-1\.0\)\s*\+\s*(-?\d+\.?\d*)\*p\*\*\((-?\d+\.?\d*)\)'

regex = re.compile(pat)

print(regex.findall('-1007.88670550662*p**(-1.0) + 67293.8347365694*p**(-0.416543501823503)'))
```

will print `[('-1007.88670550662', '67293.8347365694', '-0.416543501823503')]`

Comment: No offense but this might discourage some people from learning regex.

Answer (score 1):

If your formats are consistent, and you don't want to deep dive into regex (check out [regex101](http://www.regex101.com) for this, btw) you could just split your way through it.

Here's a start:

```
>>> s= "-1007.88670550662*p**(-1.0) + 67293.8347365694*p**(-0.416543501823503)"
>>> a, buf, c = s.split("*p**")
>>> b = buf.split()[-1]
>>> a,b,c
('-1007.88670550662', '67293.8347365694', '(-0.416543501823503)')
>>> [float(x.strip("()")) for x in (a,b,c)]
[-1007.88670550662, 67293.8347365694, -0.416543501823503]
```

Comment: This is good idea for a solution without regex. It could be simplified like this `s.replace('*p**(-1.0) +', '*p**').split('*p**')`

Answer (score 1):

The `re` module can certainly be made to work for this, although as some of the comments on the other answers have pointed out, the corner cases can be interesting -- decimal points, plus and minus signs, etc.  It could be even more interesting; e.g. can one of your numbers be imaginary?

Anyway, if your string is always a valid Python expression, you can use Python's built-in tools to process it.  [Here is a good generic explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515357/simple-example-of-how-to-use-ast-nodevisitor) about the ast module's `NodeVisitor` class.  To use it for your example is quite simple:

```
import ast

x = "-1007.88670550662*p**(-1.0) + 67293.8347365694*p**(-0.416543501823503)"

def getnums(s):
    result = []
    class GetNums(ast.NodeVisitor):
        def visit_Num(self, node):
            result.append(node.n)
        def visit_UnaryOp(self, node):
            if (isinstance(node.op, ast.USub) and
                isinstance(node.operand, ast.Num)):
                result.append(-node.operand.n)
            else:
                ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)
    GetNums().visit(ast.parse(s))
    return result

print(getnums(x))
```

This will return a list with all the numbers in your expression:

```
[-1007.88670550662, -1.0, 67293.8347365694, -0.416543501823503]
```

The `visit_UnaryOp` method is only required for Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
import re
a,_,b,c = re.findall(r"[\d\-.]+", subject)
print(a,b,c)
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/x393QT)

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer MooingRawr's answer as it is simple, I would extend it a bit to cover more situations.

A floating point number can be converted to string with surprising variety of formats:

- Exponential format (eg. `2.0e+07`)
- Without leading digit (eg. `.5`, which is equal to `0.5`)
- Without trailing digit (eg. `5.`, which is equal to `5`)
- Positive numbers with plus sign (eg. `+5`, which is equal to `5`)
- Numbers without decimal part (integers) (eg. `0` or `5`)

**Script**

```
import re

test_values = [
    '-1007.88670550662*p**(-1.0) + 67293.8347365694*p**(-0.416543501823503)',
    '-2.000e+07*p**(-1.0) + 1.23e+07*p**(-5e+07)',
    '+2.*p**(-1.0) + -1.*p**(5)',
    '0*p**(-1.0) + .123*p**(7.89)'
]

pattern = r'([-+]?\.?\d+\.?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)'

for value in test_values:
    print("Test with '%s':" % value)
    matches = re.findall(pattern, value)
    del matches[1]
    print(matches, end='\n\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Test with '-1007.88670550662*p**(-1.0) + 67293.8347365694*p**(-0.416543501823503)':
['-1007.88670550662', '67293.8347365694', '-0.416543501823503']

Test with '-2.000e+07*p**(-1.0) + 1.23e+07*p**(-5e+07)':
['-2.000e+07', '1.23e+07', '-5e+07']

Test with '+2.*p**(-1.0) + -1.*p**(5)':
['+2.', '-1.', '5']

Test with '0*p**(-1.0) + .123*p**(7.89)':
['0', '.123', '7.89']
```