# parsing and manipulating user's equations python

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

My problem is a bit complicated I would like to accept input equation from the user parse it and evaluate it. I want to have the ability to change a term or variable in that equation. I really do not know where to start. Should I make my own parser? or use something like `lhs_parsed=pyparsing.parse(lhs).to_pyfunc()`
as I found in another post. I tried to execute that line but got pyparsing does not have attribute parse. I have using python 3.7.6 on windows

Comment: There is a pyparsing-based project called `plusminus` that might be helpful for you. It comes with complete parser/evaluators for basic arithmetic, algebra, trig, business, and dice rolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) of python3 to parse the equation as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515357/simple-example-of-how-to-use-ast-nodevisitor)(that one is in python2.6, but the ast module is in python3 as well). After you've recovered the Node type inside your equation you can use that to correctly evaluate your equation. [This documentation](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html) can help you in the process. This is an example on how you can visit the tree:

```
import ast

class v(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def generic_visit(self, node):

        if type(node).__name__ == "Name":
            print(type(node).__name__, node.id)
        elif type(node).__name__ == "Constant":
            print(type(node).__name__, node.value)
        else:
            print(type(node).__name__)
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

eq= 'sin(x)**2'
parsed= ast.parse(eq)
visitor = v()
visitor.generic_visit(parsed)
```

This code will print the identifier of a variable(x for example) or of a function(the **sin** funtion for example). You can also add these lines to evaluate an espression:

```
from math import sin
x = 2
print(eval(eq))
```

You can achieve a similar result by manipulating the nodes inside the **Abstract Syntax Tree** using a **NodeTransformer** as shown in [this example](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manipulating.html).

Comment: This works great but I have two questions: isn't using eval dangerous? and if I want to recompress the ast tree into string to be evaluated how can I do that

Comment: Also how can I define different versions of generic_visit. I want to use it to change the expression and that worked for me but I need to do different changes at different times

Comment: I tried using eval(copiled(tree,filename="<ast>", mode="exec") but it did not work. It resulted in an object in the variable explorer